# How can we build a timer for 5 different player using closure in R

Tags: r, closures

There are 4 separate function for starting, ending, get their duration and display their result in desc order which needs to be implemented using closure. I was trying to implement three functions first :-

```
StopWatch <- function(){
 list(strt<-function(Name = "name") Start <<- Sys.time(),
      stop<-function() End <<- Sys.time(),
      duration<-function(){ t <<- Start- End
      print(t)})
}
```

```
w<- StopWatch()
w$strt("player1")
sleep_for_a_minute()
w$stop()
w$duration()
```

When I run w$strt("player1") it give an Error: attempt to apply non-function

Answer (score 2):

The list you create in your function isn't named.  Check by running `names(w)`.  You should use `=` instead of `<-`

Answer (score 2):

As *@Tyler Smith* already [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58779985/6574038), you need `=`, because you want to assign names to `list` elements here and not really define functions.  Also you're attempting to overwrite the `t()` function (which exemplarily here yields an error), use something different.

```
StopWatch <- function() {
  list(strt=function(Name = "name") Start <<- Sys.time(),
       stop=function() End <<- Sys.time(),
       duration=function() { 
         tm <<- Start - End
         print(tm)
       })
}

w <- StopWatch()
w$strt("player1")
Sys.sleep(1)  
w$stop()
w$duration()
# Time difference of -2.27513 secs
```